# SAS Char in worddate format back to date

Tags: sas

I have a string that follows the following pattern:

"From July 29, 2018 to August 4, 2018"
"From July 22, 2018 to July 28, 2018"
"From July 15, 2018 to July 21, 2018"

I'm trying to extract the "to" date value and convert it back to date.

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover dlm='|' ;
input Week_Name : $100.;
datalines;
From July 29, 2018 to August 4, 2018
From July 22, 2018 to July 28, 2018
From July 15, 2018 to July 21, 2018
run;

data want;
set have;
RE=PRXPARSE("/to [A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+, [0-9]{4}/");
CALL prxsubstr(RE,STRIP(Week_Name),start,length);
IF START GT 0 then DO;
    END_DT_CHAR = strip(substrn(STRIP(Week_Name),start+3,length-3));
    END_DATE = input(END_DT_CHAR,anydtdte.);
end;
drop RE start   length;
run;
```

The END_DT_CHAR gets extacted ok. I get

END_DT_CHAR
August 4, 2018
July 28, 2018
July 21, 2018

But the 
    END_DATE = input(END_DT_CHAR,anydtdte.);

Comes back all NULL

Comment: NM, solved it - anydtdte32. format did the trick

Comment: DLMSTR also allows you to specify a string as a delimiter such as 'to'.